# Solvability of $A X B=C$ with $X=X^\mathrm{T}$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-rank, symmetric-matrices, pseudoinverse

I am studying symmetric solutions to the complex matrix equation
\begin{equation}
A X B=C,
\end{equation}
where $A$, $B$, and $C$ are $m\times n$, $n \times k$, and $m \times k$ complex matrices, respectively. We may further assume that these matrices are arbitrary random unstructured matrices (i.e., any submatrix of $A$, $B$, or $C$ is full-rank with probability 1). Furthermore, $X$ is the $n\times n$ matrix of unknowns, which is restricted to be symmetric (i.e., $X$=$X^\mathrm{T}$). I would like to find (and prove) a rule for obtaining the minimum $n$ that allows for a solution to this equation.

When trying to solve this problem by vectorizing, I reach a linear equation like
\begin{equation}
(B^\mathrm{T}\otimes A)\begin{bmatrix}Z_U+Z_D\end{bmatrix}v=\mathrm{vec}(C),
\end{equation}
where $Z_U$ and $Z_D$ are matrices selecting and permuting the elements of $(B^\mathrm{T}\otimes A)$ associated to the upper and lower triangular parts of $X$, respectively, and $v$ is the $n(n+1)/2$-sized vector of unique unknowns. We further know that $Z_D = K^{(n,n)}Z_U$, where $K^{(n,n)}$ is the respective conmutation matrix. What I have noticed is that the matrix $(B^\mathrm{T}\otimes A)\begin{bmatrix}Z_U+Z_D\end{bmatrix}$, and specifically $(B^\mathrm{T}\otimes A)(I+K^{(n,n)})$ where $I$ stands for identity matrix, may have rank lower than $mk$ even when $(B^\mathrm{T}\otimes A)$ has rank $mk$ (and $n(n+1)/2>mk$). I feel like there should be a way to predict how the rank of said product of matrices behaves, but I have failed to characterize it. We may also formulate this problem in terms of characterizing the right-invertibility of $(B^\mathrm{T}\otimes A)\begin{bmatrix}Z_U+Z_D\end{bmatrix}$.

Another empirical observation I noted is that, for the square case where $m=k$, the solvability of this equation is given by the simple rule $n=2m-1$, but I am not able to prove even this case.

**Edit:** When $\mathrm{rank}\left((B^\mathrm{T}\otimes A)\begin{bmatrix}Z_U+Z_D\end{bmatrix}\right)=mk$ the solution is trivially given by applying the pseudo-inverse $(.)^\dagger$ as $$v=\left((B^\mathrm{T}\otimes A)\begin{bmatrix}Z_U+Z_D\end{bmatrix}\right)^\dagger \mathrm{vec}(C),$$ and remapping $v$ to the symmetric matrix structure, but the question is about how to know if there is a solution or not. Specifically, about what values of $n$ assure solvability.

**Edit 2:** By empirical evaluation for the general case it seems that the solvability of this equation is given by the simple rule $n\geq m+k-1$. However, I would still like to find a formal proof to this rule, which I have failed to do so far.

Comment: Note that this is a repost from [mathoverflow_post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/462841/solvability-of-a-x-b-c-with-x-x-mathrmt) since I was not completely sure where it would fit best. Comments in this respect are also appreciated.

Comment: Note that a complete answer is already provided in the original post [mathoverflow_post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/462841/solvability-of-a-x-b-c-with-x-x-mathrmt).

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote, using the Kronecker Product you can write the problem as:

$$ \arg \min_{\boldsymbol{x}} \frac{1}{2} {\left\| \boldsymbol{P} \boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{q} \right\|}_{2}^{2} $$

Now, we want $\boldsymbol{x} = \operatorname{Vec} \left( \boldsymbol{X} \right) $ where $ \boldsymbol{X} \in \mathcal{S}^{n} $.

This can be written as equality constraints by a matrix $\boldsymbol{E} \in \mathbb{R}^{{n}^{2} \times {n}^{2}} $ which has only 2 non zero elements per row: $1, -1$ where $1$ for the element $i, j$ and $-1$ for the element $j, i$.

So the problem becomes Linear Least Squares with Equality constraints:

$$\begin{align}
\arg \min_{ \boldsymbol{x} } \quad & \frac{1}{2} {\left\| \boldsymbol{P} \boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{q} \right\|}_{2}^{2} \\
\text{subject to} \quad & \begin{aligned} 
\boldsymbol{E} \boldsymbol{x} & = \boldsymbol{0} \\
\end{aligned}
\end{align}$$

This has a closed form solution as in [Linear Least Squares with Equality Constraint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2376031).

Comment: Thank you, but if the equation is not solvable what you show is only useful for obtaining approximate solutions. This should lead to a similar solution as in my vectorized version of the problem when you use the pseudoinverse of the matrix of which I can't characterize the rank (this is essentially the LS estimate of the solution whenever its rank doesn't allow for a closed solution). However, I'm only interested in finding the $n$ values for which the optimization you show gives a squared error of precisely $0$.

Comment: @Juan, This is a solution to the problem in your title. If a solution exists, it will find it. If not, it will give the LS solution. Indeed, it doesn't analyze the solvability of the problem, just yield the solution.

Comment: But the question is about the solvability of that equation, not about the solution for it. In what I wrote for this question the solution is trivially obtained whenever it is solvable, but the issue is to know when it is solvable.

Comment: I guess I may edit the post to remark that a solution is already available.